# Difficulty starting Kafka from docker

Tags: docker

Docker newb here - I've defined a simple image that grabs and extracts kafka, exposes the port and then tries to start the server.

For some reason it's not seeing the file as executable in the docker container.

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jre-alpine

COPY start-kafka.sh /

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/"
RUN chmod a+x start-kafka.sh
RUN wget http://apache.mirror.gtcomm.net/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz
RUN gzip -d kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz
RUN tar -xvf kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tar
RUN ls -la
RUN echo $PATH
EXPOSE 9092
CMD ["start-kafka.sh"]
```

My start-kafka.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /kafka_2.11-2.1.0
ls
cd bin
ls
cat kafka-server-start.sh
exec "/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh" "/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/server.properties"
```

When running docker run -p 9092:9092 kafka1 I get the output of the cat command then the following...

```
/start-kafka.sh: exec: line 8: /kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh: not found
```

Help please!

Comment: `chmod +x kafka-server-start.sh`?

Comment: Did an ls -la in my start-kafka.sh script..   -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1376 Nov  9 19:50 kafka-server-start.sh

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this with help from a colleague - the kafka-server-start.sh requires bash, which the alpine image didn't provide. Added the installation of bash to my script and all was good!